# Проблема с background фоновым изображением

Tags: html, адаптивная-верстка, scss, background, img

[image: Вот что происходит]

```
<body>
<header class="welcome">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    </div>
</header>
@import "nullstyle.scss";

.welcome {
    height: 770px;
     background-image: url(../img/bg.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Пробовал уже разные способы для постановки изображения. Все свойства background-size, в перемешке с height и widht и всего лишь не могу растянуть 200 пикселей вперед, чтобы это было адаптивно. Что я делаю не так? Или изображение маленькое как его вообще под разрешению 2к + вставлять? А если разрешение меньше то вообще никак не получается его сделать резиновым. Вот что происходит на экране в 2 случаях:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/6R9br.jpg (не смог просто залить)

Comment: Вообще у меня постоянно такая проблема, может кто подсказать как всегда такие проблемные изображения ставить?

Comment: В чем проблема-то? У вас стоит высота блока welcom - 770px, картинка занимает всю его высоту и ширину. У вас разрешение стоит 2430x1723, при таких параметрах, блок и должен себя таким образом вести. На второй картинке (с белой полосой справа) вы, судя по всему, указываете ширину блока. Важный момент, вы же понимаете, что вы выставляете не высоту/ширину изображение, а высоту/ширину БЛОКА. Также уточните, что конкретно вы хотите видеть на экране, это значительно упростит ответ.

Comment: @xydope https://imgur.com/a/yXA3O3D , спасибо дали мне новый посыл, но я до сех пор не представляю как это осуществить. Я буду пытаться

Comment: Попробуйте использовать медиазапросы. Если экран больше 1920x1080, то блок занимает 70vh, в этом случае картинка будет выглядеть более-менее пропорционально.